# How to change sql table values to header of result with aggregate function

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table named sales_table like below

| Date | type | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-12-01 | Cash | 100 |
| 2021-12-01 | Google Pay | 200 |
| 2021-12-01 | Google Pay | 300 |
| 2021-12-02 | Cash | 100 |
| 2021-12-02 | Google Pay | 200 |
| 2021-12-02 | Google Pay | 200 |

I want need some query in SQL so that I can get data in below format.

| Date | Cash | Google Pay |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-12-01 | 100 | 500 |
| 2021-12-02 | 100 | 400 |

Can anyone please help with this?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: If a MasterCard row is inserted later, do you expect a MasterCard column too in the result?

Comment: @shadow, how did you know this is a MySQL and not MS SQL Server question?

Comment: @jarlh don't worry, I'll find an ms sql server duplicate one soon.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this

```
select sale.Date
, sum(case when sale.type = 'Cash' 
           then sale.amount end) as Cash
, sum(case when sale.type = 'Google Pay' 
           then sale.amount end) as "Google Pay" 
from sales_table as sale
where sale.type in ('Cash', 'Google Pay')
group by sale.Date
order by sale.Date
```

Or this  *(Sql Server)*

```
select *
from (
  select "Date", "type", amount 
  from sales_table
) src
pivot (
  sum(amount) 
  for "type" in ('Cash', 'Google Pay')
) pvt
```

Comment: As if there weren't dozens of duplicates for pivot tables for both mysql and ms sql server...